# server.tsx module not found when building docker image

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, create-react-app, docker-build, react-scripts

When running my create-react-app server on my local machine with `npm run start`, the server starts and works fine. However, when attempting to dockerize my app, I get the error:

```
#12 2.029 Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/sms-fe/src/server.tsx'
#12 2.029     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:15)
#12 2.029     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:27)
#12 2.029     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
#12 2.029     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
#12 2.029   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
#12 2.029   requireStack: []
#12 2.029 }
#12 2.033 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#12 2.034 npm ERR! errno 1
```

It seems it can't find the the `server.tsx` file. However, despite there being no physical `src/server.tsx` file on my local machine, the app still works fine. I'm guessing that `react-scripts` possibly is doing something in the background but I'm not sure what.

Any ideas?

Here are my Docker and package.json files.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.7-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/sms-fe

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g typescript

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 8080 

# RUN node scripts/start.js && node ./src/server.tsx
RUN ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start && node ./src/server.tsx",
...
```

Comment: Just came across this. Check it out to see if it helps: https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/

Comment: Thanks @rexessilfie. I had a look over it. In the end I found the issue. I ran the container without the `npm run start` command. I think executed the shell inside the container and found that there was no `package-lock.json`. By the looks of my script I was running the `COPY` command after the `npm install`. This probably overrided things and for some reason didn't copy the `package-lock.json` file. Swapping these around fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with running my `COPY` command after `npm install`. To cause further issues. It also seems the first of two copy commands (`COPY package*.json ./`) didn't copy my `package-lock.json` file or it was overidden, possibly by the second `COPY` command.

This was discovered by:

1. Removing the `npm run start` command.
2. Running the container so that it doesn't exit.
3. Executing shell on the container and looking at the file structure.
4. Running npm install.

The fix:

Ensuring the `COPY` command is run before `npm install`

e.g.

```
COPY . ./

RUN npm install
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved many hours today. <3